# scipy opening image in okular

Tags: python, scipy, python-3.5, imshow

Whenever I try to show an image using scipy, it opens the image in okular with an error dialog pop-up on top of that saying `Could not open /home/username/%i`. This the code that I am executing:

```
    from scipy import misc
    f = misc.imread('images.jpeg')
    misc.imshow(f)
```

This is little irritating because I use okular to view my pdf files. If I uninstall okular and do the same, the image opens in a tcl window which is ok.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.18.1/reference/generated/scipy.misc.imshow.html#scipy.misc.imshow) tell you that you can change the viewer used by defining the environment-variable `SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER`.

You can either change this globally on your system or do this within your code like this:

```
import os
os.environ["SCIPY_PIL_IMAGE_VIEWER"]="display"  # i'm not sure what you want here
```